# time.sleep(5) will make entire program to sleep?

Tags: python, xmpp, kivy

In my program, i have to wait for some installations to complete. The following is the pseudo Code for the same:

```
    Clock.schedule_once(self.instantiate_module1,2)
    Clock.schedule_once(self.instantiate_module2,2)
    while (instantiation is not done)
          time.sleep(4)

    Continue Execution
But the installations are never done.
```

Here sleep will keep the entire program(if we have multiple threads) to pause/sleep?
How sleep method works?

Comment: do you want to wait for each thread to complete?

Comment: @vks: My understanding of 'Clock.schedule_once' is, it will execute after two seconds. Will it execute in different thread? If yes, how do i listen for execution completion? (Thanks for your replay vks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.sleep` is blocking the main thread, where the clock also runs. A simple solution is to just clock schedule your checking function every four seconds instead, and cancel it when the installation finishes.